# Too many connections cause node crash

Tags: node.js, promise

My node program is crashed without any log.
I run the program below with `node index.js`.

```js
const childProcess = require('child_process')
const util = require('util');
const exec = util.promisify(childProcess.exec);

console.time('total');
console.log("start");
const urlList = Array(500).fill("https://google.com");
const pList = urlList.map(function(url) {
    return exec('curl --max-time 20 --connect-timeout 10 -iSs "' + url + '"', function (error, stdout, stderr) { });
});
Promise.all(pList).then(() => {
    console.timeEnd('total');
}).catch((e) => {
    console.log('error: ' + e);
});
```

I think it might be memory problem because of too many curl connections.
But how to figure out it?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: If you don't even see the console.log("start") this may be crashing before the exec curl. Have you tryed to run in verbose mode ?

Comment: It didn't crash. It just completed without resolving the promise and logging the total time, since you were still passing a callback to the promisified function.

Answer (score 0):

because `util.promisify(childProcess.exec)()` only receive string not string and function
So you must change it into

```
const pList = urlList.map(function(url) {
    return exec('curl --max-time 20 --connect-timeout 10 -i "' + url + '"');
});
```

Comment: It's still crashed even I change that part...

Comment: Could you provide me err message , so I can help you out